# how to configure the base report to printer in openerp?

Tags: python, printing, report, openerp-7

I have installed in base_report_to_printer module for print direct to printers and installed all the dependences like pycups all the things'. I have configure the printing action and default printer in user profile. Now I want to print to direct printer when I hit the print button?

I have followed below procedure:

- After installing enable the "Printing / Print Operator" option under access rights to give users the ability to view the print menu.
- To show all available printers for your server, use the Settings/Configuration/Printing/Update Printers from CUPS wizard.
- Then go to the user profile and set the users printing action and default printer.

I want to print direct to printers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install pycups library into the server.

Step to install pycups

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
sudo pip install pycups
```

Then you need to configure **cloud printers** into your google accounts.
In google cloud printers you will see IPP of the printers.

You need to add new printer into your server using that `IPP`.
So when user request print to that printer then server identifies request and forward that request to appropriate location.

To show all available printers for your server, use the Settings/Configuration/Printing/Update Printers from CUPS wizard.

You can configure reports printing action for each report or for each user as well.

Comment: Thank you Emipro Technologies but im working on Windows Platform in that i can't install the pycups im trying to install pycups but its getting so many error i have seen pycups installation in windows i didnt get accurate solution  if u know please share it that is more helpful  to me...

Comment: Is your server OS is window? or you are using window client ?

Comment: Server os is windows I'm using azure

Comment: For windows flavor you need to use `gcp://gmailid%40gmail.com/1ad33b3b-61ed-1c29-7eaa-5a342bcfa4d2(printer id)`.
IPP is not there for windows, when you add any printer to cloud you will see printer id. and for printer administration you can use `http://localhost:631/`